# How to create an Xtext wildcard terminal rule for any combination of characters?

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I want to write a rule for the following

```
INTEGER X;
IF GIBBERISH THEN
    X = 10;
ELSE
    X = 15;
END;
```

In the above program I want to write a terminal rule for any character in GIBBERISH like `code('Xfr)` or `ADEF==DCF+1` something like that.

I wrote a terminal rule

```
// GIBBERISH
terminal GIBBERISH: (.)* ;
```

And  I got this error

```
The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same 
input: RULE_ID,RULE_INT,RULE_STRING,RULE_ML_COMMENT,RULE_WS,RULE_ANY_OTHER
```

I also understand why this error message is being showed but anyways I want to override this.

Answer (score 0):

Just not extend your grammar from Terminals rule. Remove extend string from grammar head and all these terminals will be removed.